# Angular 6 returning value from service

Tags: angular, observable, angular5, angular6

I'm learning angular and I have a problem with getting data from service.  This is my code
First simple model to store data.

```
//user.model.ts
export class UserModel {
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;

  deserialize(input: any): this {
    Object.assign(this, input);
    return this;
  }
}
```

Auth service.
I need to save data to UserModel to get to this data from all code.

```
//auth.service.ts

export class AuthService implements OnDestroy {
  private user: UserModel;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getUser() Observable<UserModel> {
    return Observable.of(this.user);
  }

  login(login: string, password: string) {
    const data = {'login': login, 'password': password};
    return this.http.post(`login/`, data)
      .map(token => {
        this.user = new UserModel().deserialize(token);
    });
  }
}

//login.component.ts
// ......
this.authService.login(username, password).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  },
);
```

And after login and the home page

```
//home.component.ts
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  user: any;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {    
    this.authService.getUser().subscribe(data =>{
      this.user = data;
      console.log(this.user);
    });  
  }
}
```

I got:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
```

How to correct getting saved data from service?

**EDIT**
I found a bug

```
getUser() Observable<UserModel> {
  return Observable.of(this.user);
}
// should be 
getUser(): Observable<UserModel> {
  return Observable.of(this.user);
}
```

But now I have undefined in my console output (from HomeComponent)

**EDIT 2**

It looks like user initialization inside map in login method doesn't initialised my variable. Does anyone know why?

```
login(login: string, password: string) {
const data = {'login': login, 'password': password};
return this.http.post(`login/`, data)
  .map(token => {
    this.user = new UserModel().deserialize(token);
});
```

}

Comment: Are you injecting `authService` in your `login.component.ts` ?

Comment: yes, I have problem with HomeComponent

Comment: I would recommend using something other than the `Observable.of` method. You could use a `Subject`, here is a StackBlitz I created to demonstrate your use cas: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mlc-app-init-1qdruy